# Is there an "identity" template in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

On MediaWiki, is it possible to define a template with the following output?

(note: normalization of non-line-breaking whitespace is okay)

```
Invocation            Expanded output

{{Identity|test}}     test
{{Identity|test|}}    test|
{{Identity||}         |
{{Identity|a b|c}}    a b|c
{{Identity|a|b=c|d}}  a|b=c|d
```

Perhaps this is even readily available in some extension, though I'm not sure what extensions are available to me on the host site. (I do know it has ParserFunctions)

If not possible, is there some maximal subset of this functionality that *can* be implemented?

Comment: Even if there was, I'm not exactly sure what you would need this for. Are you actually looking for some kind of escaping function?

Comment: The purpose is to allow a `{{#switch` or similar to expand into a table row.  I need to escape pipes that could be misinterpreted as belonging to the `#switch`.  If this is a textbook case of the XY problem, let me know.

Comment: See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Other for how this is usually done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bergi answered in comments by solving the XY problem.

The use case was to allow parser functions to expand to stuff containing table rows/cells without their pipes being interpreted as delimiting arguments to the parser function template.  The solution historically used is to simply define [`Template:!`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Template:!) and [`Template:!!`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Template:!!) that expand to `|` and `||` respectively, so that the table delimiters can be escaped by typing

```
Syntax   Escaped form
|        {{!}}
|-       {{!}}-
||       {{!!}}
```

Newer versions of MediaWiki now even treat `{{!}}` as [a magic word](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Other), guaranteeing that it is always treated as part of table syntax and never as a delimiter to a template.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably do it with [Scribunto frames](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto/Lua_reference_manual#frame.args), aside from whitespace trimming and preprocessing changes. Seems like an exercise in pointlessness though.